# what thing i should change from this code

Tags: c

I want to make a program to count the sum of digits in a string but only using `stdio.h`
but the program needs to count until its less than 10
so the example you input 56 it would be  `5+6=11` then `1+1=2` and so on

here's my code. For now I'm just confused how to check if its whether more than 9 or not

```
#include<stdio.h>

int plus(int n);
int main(void)
{
    int n, digit, test;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    test = plus(n);
    while(test != 0)
    {
        if(test > 9)
            plus(test);
        else
            break;  
    }
    printf("%d", test);
}

int plus(int n)
{
    int digit=0,test=0;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        digit = n%10;
        test = test + digit;
        n = n/10;       
    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: If you're supposed to "make a program to count the sum of digits in a **string**" (emphasis mine) then why aren't you reading a string?

Comment: `while (test > 9) test = plus(test);`

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the value returned by `plus` function in the `while` body.

You can change the condition in while to check whether it is greater than 9 or not, and assign test as `test = plus(test);`

So, your while will look like this.

```
while(test > 9)
{
    test=plus(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively call the function **plus()** until the value returned by it becomes less than 10. Like shown below:

```
int main(void)
 {
    int n=56;
    while(n> 10)
    {
      n = plus(n);
    }
    printf("%d", n);
}
```